# Will I need kanji in Japan

Tags: hiragana

So I’m trying to learn Japanese since there is a slim chance that I will go to Japan for a tournament next year,I want to know if it’s necessary to learn kanji just for a few days in Japan??if you are a Japanese or live in Japan do you need to know kanji so you can go to stores and stuff??

Answer (score 1):

You won't really need Kanji if you're only staying in Japan for a couple of days. Perhaps an online translator would be enough. But when living in Japan, I would defenitely recommend you to learn kanji. Some words are pronounced the exact same way where you would have to "guess" the meaning of it using the words around it. As a native, it's also very much easier to read long sentences with kanji rather than without them. (Kind of like reading english with no spaces or punctuation)