# Should I learn kanji

Tags: kanji

Is kanji important in the Japanese language?

Comment: Considering you asked [the same question two days ago](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95635/78) and it was closed, I wouldn't have high hopes for this one.  Also, maybe read up on [what type of questions are allowed here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very subjective topic and it really depends on what your end goals are / why you're learning the language.

Since you're learning it to go on a short trip, I would recommend learning at least some basic kanji, as there may be some situations in which you would have to read them, however I don't think it's necessary, and you could definitely survive without learning any.

I could be wrong though; I'd just say learn them if you feel like you want to, and don't if you don't.

Comment: Well since you guys said I will learn some basic kanji,not too many though because I will be there for a few days,also I finished hiragana today:)

Answer (score 1):

You really should, because it is really an important part of their language.

Comment: Well since you guys said I will learn some basic kanji,not too many though because I will be there for a few days,also I finished hiragana today:)